# Calling javascript function after Ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html

I'm building a backoffice and I've a gallery of images with a dropdown

selector:

```
<section>
<label for="dropdown_gallery">Selecione a página que pretende carregar</label>
<div>                   
    <select name="dropdown_gallery" id="dropdown_gallery" onchange="loadXMLDoc(this.value)">
            <optgroup label="Páginas">
                <option value="">Selecione Página</option>
                <option value="empresa">Empresa</option>
                <option value="destaque">Empresa - Destaque</option>
                <option value="portfolio_design">Portfólio - Design Gráfico</option>
                <option value="portfolio_stands">Portfólio - Stands e Decorações</option>
                <option value="portfolio_publicidade">Portfólio - Publicidade Exterior</option>
                <option value="portfolio_promocoes">Portfólio - Promoções e Animações</option>
                <option value="portfolio_eventos">Portfólio - Eventos</option>
                <option value="portfolio_som">Portfólio - Som Ambiente</option>
            </optgroup>
        </select> 
    </select>
</div>
</section>
<ul class="gallery" id="image_gallery">
<?php
    $files = glob('images/*.{jpg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
        foreach($files as $file) {
            echo "<li>
                    <a href='".$file."' title='some Description'>
                        <img src='".$file."' width='116' height ='116' alt=''>
                    </a>
                </li>";
        }
?>
</ul>
```

When this is executed the first time, It generates well the code:

```
<li>
    <a rel="wl_gallery" href="images/3.jpg" title="some Description">
        <img src="images/3.jpg" alt="" height="116" width="116">
    <span><a class="edit">Edit</a><a class="delete">Delete</a></span></a>
</li>
```

But then if I select another option I make an Ajax call:

```
<script>
        function loadXMLDoc(page)
        {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else
          {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
          {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
            document.getElementById("image_gallery").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
          }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","load_images.php?q="+page,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        }
</script>
```

The load_images.php is the same code from before, but the HTML code generated is different:

```
<li>
    <a href="images/3.jpg" title="some Description">
        <img style="top: 0px;" src="images/3.jpg" alt="" height="116" width="116">
    </a>
</li>
```

I guess this is because the first time is created the page, it calls a JS function that i have in another file (wl_Gallery.js):

```
$.fn.wl_Gallery = function (method) {   
   ...   
}
```

Is any way that I can call this JS function after the AJAX call too?

**EDIT:**

Another thing that I noticed is that in Firefox Developers Tool I have a little ev, the first the page is called, but not on the second time like this:

[image]

Comment: So, what is the value of `xmlhttp.responseText` in your ajax call?  And, what do you want us to do about that if it's different than your original HTML?  This seems like basic debugging on your part to discern what is different and then maybe you can ask how you deal with whatever is causing you a problem.  Right now, you've offered no specifics except that the ajax call returns different HTML than the page originally contained.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, try editing this part of your code

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
    document.getElementById("image_gallery").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    // add this line
    $("#image_gallery").wl_Gallery({});
}
```

Comment: the result is the same

Comment: Please see the printscreen i took

Comment: Another thing, I run the code with debugging and inside the method that is called, i have an If like this:

if (!$this.data('wl_Gallery')) {
.....
}

The first time the code goes in this If, after the ajax call didn't entered the If, I guess the problem is this now, what is that $this.data ?